# When uploading a picture to a product from the admin It doesn't show up on the front end until I run catalog:images:resize

Tags: magento2, product-images, cache, url

Is there something else I can do to show the picture on the frontend? Without the catalog:images:resize command??

Thanks!

Comment: you try php bin/magento i:rei command??

Comment: Yes, sadly didn't work

Comment: so you try cron run command